# How can I check the null cell value in the DataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

How can I check the null cell value in a DataGridView in C#?
I've used `DBNull` for checking, but it is not working.

Can anybody help me?

The code I currently have is:

```
string[] ar=new string[dataGridView1.Columns.Count];
for(int i=0;i<dataGridView1.Columns.Count;i++)
{
   if (dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value != DBNull.Value)
   {
     if (i != 0)
    {
       ar[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString ();
    }
    else
    {
       ar[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: when you say you have tried DBNull, did you try something like `if (dataGridView1.Rows[j].Cells[1].Value == DBNull.Value)` ?

Comment: thanx for ur help but i've already used this condition but it is not working correctly. But i got my answer of this question

Comment: Please post the code that you've tried so far. Explain to us *how* it's "not working". What result did you get, compared to what result did you expect?

Comment: i don't know how to attach code ? can u tell me?

Comment: I formatted the code for you already. You just indent each line by 4 spaces, or select the block and click the `{}` on the toolbar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use this

```
if(!Convert.IsDBNull(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value))
{
    if (i != 0)
    {
       ar[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString ();
    }
    else
    {
       ar[i] = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[i].Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: The correcte function name is `Convert.IsDBNull` I will edit to fix the typo.